# Changing tick label colour in mpld3

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, mpld3

I am trying to plot stuff using matplotlib and mpld3.  This is the code I use to generate my graph:

```
_fig = plt.figure()
_pl = _fig.add_subplot(111)
_pl.plot(_times, _values)
_pl.set_xlabel("Time")
_pl.set_ylabel("Value")

_pl.tick_params(direction="out", axis="both", colors="white", which="both")
_pl.xaxis.label.set_color("white")
_pl.yaxis.label.set_color("white")

_data = mpld3.fig_to_html(_fig)
.... send to client to be rendered
```

A graph is created and all the dynamic controls work. "Time" and "Value" labels get printed in white but tick labels in black.

If I skip mpld3 and test it with plt.show(), all tick labels get printed in white. When I check the javascript code generated by mpld3, I do not seem to detect the colour setting there for tick labels.

If I use another parameter, like font size, in tick_params it does have an effect. Only the colour gets ignored, which causes the labels to be printed in black on a dark blue background.

How do I change this?

Edit:

When inspecting the actual page rendered, there seems to be a "fill" property that determines the colour.

```
div#fig_el249691400950908834083380374260 .mpld3-xaxis text 
{font-family:sans-serif; font-size:10px; fill:black; stroke:none; }
```

I tried overriding this in css but I could not figure out how to do it. This seems to override whatever I set elsewhere. It appears mpld3 sets the colour of the tick label, but how do I modify this?

Hannu

Comment: This [list of known issues](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/wiki) may be of interest, where it says: "tick locations and tick formatting is not accurately reflected".

Comment: Maybe it is a feature then. The quick and dirty workaround is to change the background colour. My page does not look as nice as it did before with a solid navy blue background, but at least the labels are visible.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well; I understand that tick formatting is not supported, but (given that this is unlikely to be supported anytime soon) a better workaround would be a solution to override it in CSS. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Ok my work around for the moment is to change the mpld3 javascript library so that the axes and tick labels are coloured white. I change line 290 and 291 of mpld3.v0.3.js to read: `fontcolor: "white",` and `axiscolor: "white",`. A shame to have no way to set this as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mpld3 only supports a subset of matplotlib's full capabilities, and tick formatting is one of the many things that is not yet supported. There is a partial list of these missing features on the [mpld3 wiki](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/wiki).